# $(\mathcal{S}\mathcal{T})^3=\mathcal{S}^2=+1$ mistake in CFT big yellow book?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, path-integral, research-level, partition-function

In Conformal Field Theory Philippe by Di Francesco, Pierre Mathieu David Sénéchal

Sec 10.l. Conformal Field Theory on the Torus

[image]

eq.10.9 says the modular transformation $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{S}$ satisfies

1.
$$
(\mathcal{S}\mathcal{T})^3=\mathcal{S}^2=+1
$$

2. But I also heard that given chiral central charge $c$
   $$
   (\mathcal{S}\mathcal{T})^3=e^{2 \pi i c/8}\mathcal{S}^2
   $$
3. I also heard that
   $$
   (\mathcal{S}\mathcal{T})^6 =\mathcal{S}^4=+1
   $$

How can these three statements all be true? Please kindly correct any mistake any of us made above and provide an explanation?

Comment: Heard where? In which context?

Comment: For the second definition, are there certain constraints on what $c$ should be or what values it can be? Or is it that the RHS must be equal to one, so that puts constraints on $c$ in order to give unity? Also, where did statement 3 come from since this just seems like statement number 1 but with higher powers.